# Sound Menu Album Art is not rounded

Tags: 10.10, indicator-sound

My album art on my sonud menu (maverick) isn't being rounded. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the behaviour of this has been changed since the release of Maverick 10.10.

In October 2010 Maverick was released with version `0.4.7-0ubuntu2` of the `indicator-sound` package - this used rounded corners. Updates mean we are now on version `0.5.0.1-0ubuntu2` which doesn't use rounded corners.

So non-rounded corners is now the standard behaviour.

See also [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sound/+bug/640999) (the new design avoids the bug shown in the image below):

[image: Screenshot of Bug]